# MySQL Many-To-Many Query Problem

Tags: sql, mysql, many-to-many

Here's my problem. I have a many-to-many table called 'user_has_personalities'. In my application, users can have many personalities, and a personality can belong to many users.

The table has two integer columns, user_id and personality_id.

What I need to do is get all users that have at least all of the personalities (a set of personality_ids of variable size) which I supply to the query.

For an example, I'd like to get all users that have personalities with ids 4, 5, 7, but can also have some other personalities. But I need the query to work for a variable number of wanted personality ids, like 4, 5, 7, 9, 10 for an example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query does the job:

```
select  user_id
from    user_has_personalities
where   personality_id in (<list-of-personality-ids>)
group by user_id
having count(*) = <numer-of-items-in-IN-list>
```

You need to supply a comma-separated list of personality ids for `<list-of-personality-ids>` and you also need to provide the number of items in th elist. Sticking to your example, you would get:

```
select  user_id
from    user_has_personalities
where   personality_id in (4,5,7)
group by user_id
having count(*) = 3
```

this ensures you only get users that have all these personalities.

Comment: this just tells if they have one of the personality_id's. The question explicitly says ALL of the ids.

Comment: @Evan: this query tells if the user has all of the ids.

Comment: I see what you're doing. Nice.

Comment: This is the fastest and most elegant way to do it! Great!!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT user_id
        FROM    user_has_personalities
        ) uhpo
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    user_has_personalities uhpi
        WHERE   uhpi.user_id  = uhpo.user_id
                AND personality_id IN (4, 5, 6, 9, 10)
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
        )
```

Offset value should be `1` less than the number of items in the `IN` list.

If you have your personality list in a dedicated table, use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT user_id
        FROM    user_has_personalities
        ) uhpo
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    perslist p
        JOIN    user_has_personalities uhpi
        ON      uhpi.user_id = uhpo.user_id
                AND uhpi.personality_id = p.id
        ) =
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    perslist
        )
```

For this to work correctly (and fast), you need to have a `UNIQUE` index on `user_has_personalities (user_id, personality_id)` (in this order).

If you have a `users` table and almost all users have a record in `user_has_personalities`, then substitute it in place of the `DISTINCT` nested query:

```
SELECT  user_id
FROM    users uhpo
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    perslist p
        JOIN    user_has_personalities uhpi
        ON      uhpi.user_id = uhpo.user_id
                AND uhpi.personality_id = p.id
        ) =
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    perslist
        )
```

Comment: +1 for general mastery and wizard-ness :) Quassnoi, I love your blog and I linked you. I would like your blog even more if you'd open comments on it, but obviously its your prerogative to leave it as is. Anyway, cheers and keep it up :)

Comment: @Roland: every article in category `Miscellaneous` has comments enabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.user_id
FROM user_has_personalities a
JOIN user_has_personalities b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND b.personality_id = 5
JOIN user_has_personalities c ON a.user_id = c.user_id AND b.personality_id = 7
WHERE a.personality_id = 4
```

It would be easy enough to generate this list programatically, but it's not exactly as easy as supplying a set.  On the other hand, it is efficient.